# Why `FBVisualComponent::GetQWidgetAddress()` in Motion Builder SDK always return 0？

Tags: motionbuilder

Why `FBVisualComponent::GetQWidgetAddress()` in Motion Builder SDK always return 0？

I want to get the address of qwidget inside a `FBLabel`, and call some native QT method on it.

However, I found that the method always return a 0.

I wonder if this method works.

I'm using MotionBuilder2019.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that MotionBuilder uses QWidget encapsulated by theirselves, instead of native QT widgets like QLabel or QPushButton. It means that even if you can get the address of these QWidgets, you can do nothing to them. If you really want to make a nice user interface, just use the QT via `FBNativeHolder`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).